# Irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ on $\Bbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I would like to find the irreducible polynomial on $\Bbb{Q}$ of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$.
How can I do that ? First time I see this kind of question, I can find a polynomial $X^2-2$ witch $\sqrt{2}$ is a roots, but I don't understand what I need.

> To conclude that the polynomial is irreducible I can use Eisentein criterion but can someone explain how can I find the polynomial ?

Comment: $a=\sqrt2+\sqrt7$, $a^2 = 2 + 2\sqrt{14} + 7$, $(a^2-9)^2=56$ - it's your polynom (with roots $\pm\sqrt2\pm\sqrt7$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ satisfies $(a-\sqrt{2})^2-7=0$, or $a^2-5=2\sqrt{2}a$, so $(a^2-5)^2=8a^2$

Comment: Ok, so now I just need to check that the polynomial is irreducible ?

Comment: @Gato Exactly. Another hint : check that $\sqrt{7}\not\in{\mathbb Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.